# MONGO + SPRING: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mongo:db-factory'

Tags: spring, mongodb, inversion-of-control

How fix this error?

Context content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo" xsi:schemaLocation=
           "http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
<mongo:db-factory dbname="#{properties.getProperty('mongo.database')}"
                  password="#{properties.getProperty('mongo.password')}"
                  username="#{properties.getProperty('mongo.user')}"
                  port="#{properties.getProperty('mongo.port')}"
                  host="#{properties.getProperty('mongo.host')}"/>
```

Spring and Mongo versions:

```
4.3.2.RELEASE
3.3.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing the schema location for `mongo` namespace:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xmlns:mongo="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/data/mongo/spring-mongo.xsd
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
                  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.2.xsd">
```